# Xero-api for pagination not working

Tags: node.js, pagination, xero-api

I am using Xero as a trial version.
I have 100+ contacts, Now I want to add pagination through NodeJS API.
Read the documentation of it (https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/contacts) it specify but doesn't work.

My code like this:-

```
let paging = await xeroClient.core.contacts.getContacts({page: 1})
```

I have call the function where passing page is a optional parameter but it display all the contacts for me.

Is there my mistake for passing parameter??

Answer (score 0):

I have not used node.js with [XeroApi](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node) but from the documentation you can try the following:

```
/* Called per page */
const onContacts = (err, response, cb) => {
    let contacts = response.data;
    if (response.finished) // finished paging
        ....
    cb(); // Async support
};

xeroClient.core.contacts.getContacts({ pager: {start:1 /* page number */, callback: onContacts}})
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`Oh no, an error: ${err}`);
    });
```

Check the part with the pager.